# Calling Method Attempt Not Working Due to Guard Function

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys its me again sorry, after surfing the internet, I haven't found the answer to this error. I tried other things but some said that needs to use passports, also I already edit my auth.php and add some new providers like ***'employees'*** and also I added a guard ***'employee'***

EmployeeLoginController.php

```
class EmployeeLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:employee');
    }

    public function username(){
        return 'empId';
    }

    public function showLoginForm(){
        return view('auth.employee-login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request){

        // Validate the form data
        $this->validate($request,[
            'empId' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        //Store requested data into a variable credentials
        $credentials = [
            'empId' => $request->input('empId'),
            'password' => $request->input('password')
        ];

        // Attempt to log the user in
        if(Auth::guard('employee')->attempt($credentials)){
            // If successful, redirect to their intended location
            return redirect()->intended(route('employee.dashboard'));
        }

        // If unsuccessful, redirect back to the login with form data
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('empId'));
    }
}
```

This is my model

Employee.php

```
class Employee extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'employee';

    protected $table = 'EmpUsersInfo';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'empId', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

auth.php

```
    <?php

return [

   
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'employee' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'employees',
        ],

        'employee-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'employees',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'employees' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Employee::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'employees' => [
            'provider' => 'employees',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 15,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: **Undefined method 'attempt'** , I think because guard('guardname') doesn't have a method attempt.

Comment: depending on the guard it may not, so what driver do you have set for this new guard you setup in the config?

Comment: I already added a session guard with the name `employee` and called it on my model using `protected $guard = 'employee'`

Comment: don't know what setting that on a model would do, but how did you configure this `employee` guard?

Comment: I configured it on auth.php, I will add it above

Comment: try a `dd(get_class(Auth::guard('employee')))` to see what it is returning

Comment: `"Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard"` this is the returned value

Comment: well that definitely has an `attempt` method so that guard didn't cause the issue

Comment: do I need to make a method called attempt? and because when I do the `->` after the `guard()` it shows all the method that can be called.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was my credentials because I used an existing database which is not using a hash password and when I entered the password it didn't successfully authenticated but there were no errors.